# Display Math Should End With $$ error message

Tags: errors

I seem to be getting the same error message as several other people but I can't figure out how to apply a solution to my own work. I know the errors are occurring somewhere in here:

```
\begin{solution}
By Trichonomy, we know that x $>$ 0, x $=$ 0, or x $<$ 0.
$x\not=0$ is given so we are left with two cases:
1--If x$>$0 then $x^2$ $=$ $x\ x$
By order axiom six--if 0$\leq $x and 0$\leq $y then 0$\leq $ $x\ y$--$x^2$ $>$ 0.

2--If x$<$0 then $x^2$ $=$ $$$-1\ x$\ -1$\ x$
               $=$ $$-1^2$\ $x^2$$
                       $=$ $1\ $x^2$$
               $=$ $x^2$ $>$ 0, completing the proof.
\end{solution}
```

I get the `Display math should end with $$` error and then there is also one that tells me to insert another `$` at the beginning of the final line (the one that ends in "completing the proof") which makes no sense to me either. 
Could you please provide some insight into what I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\n}{\noindent}

\newcommand{\pp}{\parskip=0.25cm}

\newtheorem{tem}{{\sc Theorem}}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\begin{document}

\title{{\bf MA410.F13--Problem Set 1}}

\author{{\bf Lisa Snay }}

\date{}

\maketitle

\begin{questions}\pp

\question[10] Prove that if $a\in\R$ and $a\not=0$, then $a^2>0$

\end{questions}

\begin{solution}

By Trichonomy, we know that $x > 0$, $x = 0$, or $x < 0$.

$x\not=0$ is given so we are left with two cases:

1--If $x>0$ then $x^2 = x\ x$

By order axiom six--if $0\leq x$ and $0\leq y$ then $0\leq x\ y$ so $x^2 > 0$.

2--If $x<0$ then $x^2 = -1\ x\ -1\ x 

                      = -1^2\ x^2

              = 1\ x^2

              = x^2 > 0$, completing the proof.

\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh bother. I'm terribly sorry. It didn't seem to post at all properly. I'll fix it!

Comment: While I don’t know where the `solution` environment (a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)  would have been helpful) does come from, but you are not using math-mode correctly. It should be `we know that $x > 0$, $x = 0$ or $x < 0$` and so on. There is `$$$` which is recognized as display-style math (`$$`) and then a single `$` which creates the first error.

Comment: Don't do `x $>$ 0` the spacing and fonts are all wrong if you do that, the expression is all math, so the markup should be `$x > 0$`, if you didn't have so many `$ ` it would be easier to spot where you have `$$ `

Comment: Alright. This is my first time using the program (though you could probably already tell that) but I think I get what you're saying. I changed it to the following and get no error messages but when I do the "build output" option it only gets the title, author, and question, not my solution:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by default (it says in the comments in the class) solutions are not printed, you need the `answers` option. the error was because you can not have a paragraph break (blank line) in line math, I fixed some (not all:-) of the other issues such as obsolete font commands `\bf` and the option to the graphics package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,answers]{exam}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\n}{\noindent}

\newcommand{\pp}{\parskip=0.25cm}

\newtheorem{tem}{\textsc{Theorem}}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{MA410.F13--Problem Set 1}}

\author{\textbf{Lisa Snay }}

\date{}

\maketitle

\begin{questions}\pp

\question[10] Prove that if $a\in\R$ and $a\not=0$, then $a^2>0$

\end{questions}

\begin{solution}

By Trichonomy, we know that $x > 0$, $x = 0$, or $x < 0$.

$x\not=0$ is given so we are left with two cases:

1--If $x>0$ then $x^2 = x\ x$

By order axiom six--if $0\leq x$ and $0\leq y$ then $0\leq x\ y$ so $x^2 > 0$.

2--If $x<0$ then 
\begin{align}x^2 &= -1 x -1 x\\ 
                  &= (-1)^2 x^2\\
              &= 1 x^2\\
             & = x^2 > 0
\end{align}, completing the proof.

\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is a case showing that using `\(\)` and `\[\]` is better than indistinguishable `$$`

Comment: Shouldn't the comma in `\end{align}, completing the proof` come *before* `\end{align}`?

Comment: @Mico yes, I did say I had not fixed all the issues:-) `1--` should be using `enumerate` or similar list as well...